# How can I decrease a number by a variable repeated percentage

Tags: excel, percentage

I am working in an excel (2016) spreadsheet containing our asset register, so there are literally hundreds of rows of data spread over several sheets (one for each site). The way our charity works is that assets are depreciated by 20% a year (on the 1st of April, which is the start of our financial year). However the 20% comes of last years value and not of the initial value. (I realise that this is a little odd, and the assets will never be fully depreciated, but I can't change that). At the moment someone every year manually updates the value of the assets in the spreadsheet and I am looking to see if that can be automated. The value of an asset decreases like this:

```
year 0 -> 1000 (initial amount)
year 1 ->  800 (80% of 1000)
year 2 ->  640 (80% of 800)
year 3 ->  512 (80% of 640)
year 4 ->  410 (80% of 512 = 409.6 rounded)
year 5 ->  328 (80% of 410)
etc.
```

All I have is the **start date** and the **initial amount**, and I am trying to develop a formula that will calculate the value of the assets in the current financial year. Can anyone help me out with this.

Just to clarify, I need to have one cell with the current value (based on today's financial year), I don't want to be adding new cells/rows every year. So I am looking for a formula that takes the **start date** and the **initial amount** as input and outputs the asset's value for the current financial year.

Comment: if year 0 is in cell A1 and rest going down rows, in A2 use this formula and drag down: `=A1*.8`

Comment: Just edited the question to clarify why this i not an option. I don't want to have to add a new row every year.

Comment: How many entries are there? Could you maybe give a more detailed description (or a screenshot) of what your worksheet looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is what you have, correct me if I'm wrong.

A1 = 21.01.2010 (startdate)
B1 = 1000 (initial amount)

```
=Trunc(B1*0.8^(Year(Today())-Year(A1)))
```

This would give you the amount decreased by 20% per year, as in difference of the date today and the year given in A1.

If you only have a year in A1 like `A1 = 2010` the formula would be:

```
=Trunc(B1*0.8^(Year(Today())-A1))
```

Comment: Just clarified the question. I don't want to be using multiple rows as that would require adding new cells/rows every year.

Comment: *Oddly enough YEAR(TODAY()) doesn't work when in a single cell* - check your cell formatting, works perfectly for me.

Comment: This almost works. The only problem now is that our financial year starts on the 1st of April, so this goes wrong if the asset was bought in Jan-Mar. Will play with it a bit and see if I can get it to work and report back if I do.

Comment: OK, I have it working. Thank you so much for your help. This is what I have done (the IF statement corrects the first three months of the year, so the year change happens on 1st April): =ROUND(B1*0.8^(YEAR(TODAY()) - YEAR(A1) + IF(MONTH(A1)<=3,1,0)),0)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to @Tom's formula (which is far more 'conventional'):

```
=B1-SLN(B1,,5)
```

but the above is no more characters.

Comment: The SLN function is interesting, but I don't think it will work. I have just edited the original question to clarify what I am looking for.